# save/export all variables from make environment?

Tags: shell, makefile

for export certain variable `var`, I can do `make print-var`, if I have lines in Makefile:

```
print-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)'
```

However, it is often more convenient to save/export all variables for debug. I learned to hack the .VARIABLES to do this:

```
#MAKFILE

TEST1=test var 1
TEST2=\"test var 2\"
#TEST3=`test var'

MAKE_ENV := $(shell echo '$(.VARIABLES)' | awk -v RS=' ' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$$/')
SHELL_EXPORT := $(foreach v,$(MAKE_ENV),$(v)=$($(v))\n)
.PHONY: expvars
expvars:
    @echo "$(SHELL_EXPORT)"

print-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)'
```

This will work in many cases, however recently I encountered a problem that the make variables contain special characters which cannot appear in sh string. For example, the `TEST3`. If I uncomment this line. There will be error. What can I do to solve this problem?

How can I escape those characters automatically?

@MadScientist, Thanks a lot. But your suggested pattern still does not work. However, I use `@echo '$(*)=$(subst ','"'"',$($(*)))'`, which lets the `make print-TEST3` works fine. But `make` cannot get the newline correctly, I guess there are many '' in the SHELL_EXPORT, which messes the whole thing up:

```
#MAKFILE

TEST1=test var 1
TEST2=\"test var 2\"
TEST3=`test var'

MAKE_ENV := $(shell echo '$(.VARIABLES)' | awk -v RS=' ' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$$/')
SHELL_EXPORT := $(foreach v,$(MAKE_ENV),'$(v)=$(subst ','"'"',$($(v)))'\n)
.PHONY: expvars
expvars:
#   @echo "$(SHELL_EXPORT)" #this cause problem
    @echo $(SHELL_EXPORT)


print-%:
    @echo '$(*)=$(subst ','"'"',$($(*)))'
```

finally I solve this problem like this, instead of echo the whole thing at the end, I echo each line respectively:

```
#MAKFILE

TEST1=test var 1
TEST2="test var 2"
TEST3=`test var'

MAKE_ENV := $(shell echo '$(.VARIABLES)' | awk -v RS=' ' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$$/')
SHELL_EXPORT := $(foreach v,$(MAKE_ENV),\
          echo $(v)= '$(subst ','"'"',$($(v)))';\
          )
.PHONY: expvars
expvars:

    @- $(SHELL_EXPORT)

print-%:
    @echo '$(*)= $(subst ','"'"',$($(*)))'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a reliable "shell quote a value" by quoting the entire value with `'` (single quotes), and then replacing all single quotes in the value with `'"'"'`.  So, like this:

```
$(v)='$(subst ','"'"',$($(v)))'
```